# Approximating the solution of an overdetermined system help

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm trying to find a solution for an overdetermined system in the form Mv = w by projecting w (the solution) onto the span of the columns of M and then setting Mv equal to this projection.

```
      | 1  -2 |  | x |   | 1 |
      | -2  4 | *| y |  =| 5 |
```

Since the columns are linearly dependent, the span = span { [1; 2] }. Normalized, this vector is equal to [1/sqrt(5); -2/sqrt(5)]

```
     proj w onto span = ( [1/sqrt(5); -2/sqrt(5)] * [1; 5] ) * [1/sqrt(5); -2/sqrt(5)]
     = -9/sqrt(5)*[1/sqrt(5); -2/sqrt(5)]
     = [9/5; 18/5]
```

However, when I set the equation M*v equal to this approximate solution, I still have an overdetermined system. I thought that I followed the procedure correctly... can anyone steer me in the right direction?

Comment: Perhaps you should be doing something like least squares here?